# Can't initializing a delegate in the AppDelegate but inside a class method it works

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate

I am trying to initialize a delegate (*MyDelegate*) in the AppDelegate inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as follows:

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
[[someClassName instance] setMyDelegate:[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someVcName"]];
```

While debugging, all the calls perform well but when it returns to the AppDelegate after the above calls, MyDelegate is nil.

What is interesting is that when I try to set the delegate inside a class method I wrote, it works - the exact same code above.

Why the initializing doesn't work in the AppDelegate while it works in the class method ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Basically *@Leo* solved the problem but the solution was really straightforward since I was using *Storyboard* then the first ViewController is automatically initiated (assuming you assigned the entry point arrow icon):

**The solution:**

```
[[someClassName instance] setMyDelegate:[self.window rootViewController]];
```

Comment: have you print is it really get Appdelgate class object there?

Comment: I can't understand your question buddy

Comment: NSLog (@"%@",[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someVcName"]); check its it nil or not

Comment: Just did and it's not. As I wrote in the question: the exact code initialize the MyDelegate in the class method while in the AppDelegate it's not.

Comment: Yes buddy I got your question, I just told you before set delegate just check it you get appDelegate object or not it it is nit then you can set delete on them, may b you are creating AppDelegate object in wrong way, for that I telling you print that line and check its object get perfectly or not. Leo also trying to same thing in his answer

Comment: Again, I tried what you asked me and it works - it is NOT nil.
Also, I am using the AppDelegate file provided by Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

From the document

> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.

So,in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,you create a local viewController instance.

And,it will be dealloced after the method is done.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I set the *MyDelegate* globally rather then locally ?

Comment: It depends on when the viewController with this "someVcName " identifier  is load into memory. I can not figure out from the code you post. Why you want to set the delegate to the viewController in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions `.It is not load into memory at this time. That means nothing

Comment: Exactly what doesn't load into memory ? the viewController ?

Comment: Yes,normally only the `window.rootViewController`  is created at this time